# How to rotate a graph with a locator?

Tags: manipulate, rotation, locator

```
Manipulate[
 Graphics[Rotate[Line[{{0, 0}, p}], \[Theta], {0, 0}], 
  PlotRange -> 2], {{p, {1, 1}}, Locator}, {\[Theta], 0, 2 \[Pi]}]
```

I want to rotate a graph including a locator. The line rotated as expected, but the locator didn't rotate with the line. How can I do to rotate the whole graph?

[image]

Comment: Rotate a graph?  What graph?

Comment: @David, I drew a line with Locator, when I rotated the graph, the locator didn't move. I want to rotate the graph including the locator. Is there anyway to do it? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Again:  Rotate a graph?  *WHAT* graph?

Comment: @David I post code in my question to show what I want

Comment: But your title says "graph" and there is no graph whatsoever.  Please fix your title (at the very least).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(1) You can use `Locator` as a graphics primitive and rotate all the graphics primitives, and
 (2) use `` Experimental`AngularSlider `` to control the angle:

```
Manipulate[Graphics[Rotate[{Line[{{0, 0}, p}], Locator[Dynamic[p]]}, θ, {0, 0}], 
   PlotRange -> 2, ImageSize -> Small],
 {{p, {1, 0}}, None},
 {{θ, 0, ""}, 0, 2 π, Labeled[Experimental`AngularSlider[#, {0, 2 Pi}, 
     Experimental`BoundaryAction -> None], Row[{"θ = ", #}], Top] &}, 
 Deployed -> True]
```

[image]

To prevent the locator from going out of plot area after rotation, we can use the second argument of `Dynamic` to restrict the locator to stay within a disk of radius 2:

```
Manipulate[Graphics[Rotate[{Line[{{0, 0}, p}], 
    AbsolutePointSize[10], Red, Point[p], 
    Locator[Dynamic[p, (p = If[Norm[#] < 2, #, 2 Normalize[#]];) &], None]}, 
    θ, {0, 0}], PlotRange -> 2,  ImageSize -> Small],
 {{p, {1, 0}}, None}, 
 {{θ, 0, ""}, 0, 2 π, Labeled[Experimental`AngularSlider[#, {0, 2 Pi}, 
     Experimental`BoundaryAction -> None], Row[{"θ = ", #}], Top] &}, 
 Deployed -> True]
```

[image]

**Update:** If you want the two controls linked so that the angle is updated as the locator moves, change `Locator[...]` to

```
Locator[Dynamic[p, (p = If[Norm[#] < 2, #, 2 Normalize[#]]; θ = ArcTan @@ p) &], None]
```

Comment: +1 for the usage of `Experimental`AngularSlider` wow!! Why does it turn black at certain points?

Comment: @CATrevillian, i think it is an artifact of the screen shot image (I use ScreenToGif gif generator).

Comment: I've never heard of `Experimental`AngularSlider` before, that's solve my problem perfectly which I had gave up long time ago, thank you very much.

Comment: @pmzhu, my pleasure. Thank you for the accept.

Answer (score 3):

```
Manipulate[
 Rotate[Graphics[Plot[x^2, {x, 0, 5}]], r = ArcTan[r1[[1]]/r1[[2]]]],
 {{r1, {1, 1}}, Locator}]
```