# Rotation Slider Control

Tags: manipulate, dynamic, gui-construction, slider2d

*Mathematica* seems to support no "rotation slider" Control which might be used, for instance, in setting an angular direction ($0 \leq \theta \leq 2 \pi$) on a plane.  I couldn't find one in the documentation.  One can constrain a `Slider2D` to have a unit length, so that the resulting slider performs as I need, but that seems kludgy and the interface inelegant and non-obvious.

Is there any code creating what we might call a `SliderAngle` or equivalent, with nice graphics that can be scaled, colored, and such?  We should be able to "wind up" the control... that is continually increase the angle clockwise or counterclockwise through multiple revolutions.

Comment: ``Experimental`AngularSlider``?

Comment: see also: [Dynamic Linkage of LocatorPane and InputField](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/193020/125), [Dynamic Linkage of LocatorPane and InputField](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/160141/125), [How to rotate a graph with a locator?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/160141/125)

Comment: try ``NotebookTools`AngularSliderTest[]`` to play with features of ``Experimental`AngularSlider``

Comment: There is a [CircularWinder](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/CircularWinder/) in the Function Repository.

Comment: Oh... hadn't seen that.  Thanks.  But I don't see how to use this as a genuine `Control` (like a Slider or Slider2D).  Can you post a minimal `Manipulate` that rotates a vector using this new slider?  Regardless, my recommendation to WRI:  incorporate such a true Control into the next release—it would be very useful.

Comment: [ClockGauge](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ClockGauge.html) may be  customized to get something close to what you need.

Comment: I tried ClockGauge, but it started getting rather awkward and I never figured out how to use it as a true Control in a Manipulate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Manipulate[
 ParametricPlot[{Cos[x], Sin[3  x]}, {x, 0, 5 Pi}, 
  MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, 
  Mesh -> {{Abs @ z}},
  PlotLabel -> z, 
  MeshStyle -> Directive[Red, AbsolutePointSize @ 15]], 
{{z, Pi/4}, Experimental`AngularSlider[#] &}]
```

[image]

```
Manipulate[
 ParametricPlot[{Cos[x], Sin[3  x]}, {x, 0, 5 Pi}, 
  MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, 
  Mesh -> {{Abs@z}}, 
  PlotLabel -> Style[Round[z, Pi/32], 16], 
  MeshStyle -> Directive[Red, AbsolutePointSize@15]], 
{{z, Pi/4}, 
  Experimental`AngularSlider[#, 
    Appearance -> Dynamic @ Graphics @
       Text[Style[Round[z, Pi/32], 16], {0, 0}, {0, -1.1},  
          - Cross @ {Cos @ z, Sin @ z}], 
    FrameMargins -> 30] &}]
```

[image]

```
NotebookTools`AngularSliderTest[]
```

[image]

```
Options[Experimental`AngularSlider] // Column
```

[image]

Comment: Alright!  I'd expect nothing less from the legendary kglr.  Thanks!  ($+1$,$\checkmark$)